# Laravel application performance issue on Docker for Windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel, docker

I am trying to run my laravel application inside docker containers on my laptop (during development) and finding that the speed of the application is drastically slow when compared to running it using XAMPP for example.

My laptop is running Windows 10 Pro (64-Bit) with i7-6700HQ CPU, 16 GB RAM and SSD.

When I run my app in docker for windows, average page load time is approx **3.5 Seconds**.

Running it on local XAMPP, average page load time is approx **350 Milliseconds** (*0.35 Second*).

---

For my docker setup, I use the following `image/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.8
MAINTAINER Latheesan Kanesamoorthy

RUN apk add \
        --no-cache \
        --update \
        apache2 \
        composer \
        curl \
        php7 \
        php7-apache2 \
        php7-curl \
        php7-bcmath \
        php7-dom \
        php7-mbstring \
        php7-pdo_mysql \
        php7-session \
        php7-sockets \
        php7-tokenizer \
        php7-xml \
        php7-xmlwriter \
        php7-fileinfo \
    && mkdir -p /run/apache2 \
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log

COPY ./image/*.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/
COPY ./image/php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/99_custom.ini

RUN mkdir -p /storage/framework/testing
RUN mkdir -p /storage/framework/views
RUN mkdir -p /storage/framework/sessions
RUN mkdir -p /storage/framework/cache/data
RUN chown -R apache:apache /storage

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./src/composer.* ./
RUN composer install -n --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest

COPY src .
RUN composer dump-autoload -o -n

EXPOSE 80
```

and `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  mysql:
    container_name: myapp-mysql
    mem_limit: 512M
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myapp
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp
      MYSQL_USER: myapp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: myapp
    ports:
      - "35000:3306"

  redis:
    container_name: myapp-redis
    image: redis:latest

  redis-commander:
    container_name: myapp-redis-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    hostname: redis-commander
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
      - "7050:8081"
    links:
      - redis

  app:
    container_name: myapp-app
    mem_limit: 512M
    build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: image/Dockerfile
    env_file:
    - image/env/development
    volumes:
    - ./src:/app:cached
    ports:
      - "25000:80"
    entrypoint: httpd -DFOREGROUND
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
```

and I use the following commands to boot it up:

```
docker-compose down --remove-orphans
docker-compose up -d --build
docker exec myapp-app composer install --prefer-dist --no-suggest
docker exec myapp-app php artisan cache:clear
docker exec myapp-app php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

As you can see, the docker version uses redis as the driver for: cache, eloquent model cache, queue and session.

Locally for XAMPP, I am simply using file driver for all.

Any idea why the performance is so slow on docker?

*P.S. The reason why I want to try developing using the docker environment is so that I can keep my development and production environment identical.*

Comment: Docker performance on windows is often quite poor. There are steps you can take to improve it but it'll never be comparable with a unix system. The most impactful step would be to ensure that all your dependencies (`vendor`, `node_modules`) are installed within your container and only your project files (i.e: `app`) are on the host machine. That should speed things up somewhat. Beyond that you can use [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to get a better idea of where the bottleneck is.

Comment: That said, 350ms is still very slow so there are probably aspects of your application that are exacerbating the slowness. For comparison, it is very uncommon for my application's to take >50ms per page load _unless_ there's a lot of queries running, a query-less Laravel page usually takes <30ms to load on my macbook -- similar spec to your machine.

Comment: I have eloquent model caching, spatie/larvel-permission checking and couple of other queries running per page load. once cache warmed up, i see approx 200ms response time. So, it looks like there's no helping with docker on windows, i might as well dual boot an ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe if you tested on a linux server to check will it face the same poor performance ?

Comment: I am fairly certain the app will run fast as possible on linux. The issue is I develop on windows and I was trying to get this to run under docker, seems like windows docker is no where close to native docker on linux.

Comment: in your app container, make `/storage` a docker volume. I/O performance on a docker container filesystem is slower than in a volume, so if your app makes frequent read/write on a filesystem location, it's a good practice to make have this location on a docker volume